# Using combinators to swap images

Tags: css

I have a number of thumbnail to the left of a large image (see: http://i57.tinypic.com/fp4e47.png)

I am trying to work out how to use combinators so that when the user hovers on one of the thumbnails, the large image swaps to a corresponding enlargement of the thumbnail image.

Is this possible with CSS alone?

Thanks

Comment: You're looking for CSS sprites: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use , in CSS3 , the value in `src` attribute with a wilde mark  and the selector `~` if the structure allows you so .

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/full/dEwjs)**

```
#gallerie {
  width:800px;
  margin:auto;
}
.thumb {
  margin:1em;
}
.thumb:nth-child(2n+2) {
  float:left;
}
.thumb:nth-child(odd) {
  clear:left;  
  float:left;
}
.hold  {
  overflow:hidden;
  width:500px;
  margin:1em;
  position:relative;
}
.hold img {
  max-width:100%;
}
.hold img + img { 
  /* because we keep first image in the flow
   to size .hold and show something*/
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
[src*="nature/1"]:hover ~ .hold img[src*="nature/1"],
[src*="nature/2"]:hover ~ .hold img[src*="nature/2"] ,
[src*="nature/3"]:hover ~ .hold img[src*="nature/3"] ,
[src*="nature/4"]:hover ~ .hold img[src*="nature/4"] ,
[src*="nature/5"]:hover ~ .hold img[src*="nature/5"] ,
[src*="nature/6"]:hover ~ .hold img[src*="nature/6"] {
  display:block;
  z-index:1;
}
```

with this structure

```
<div id="gallerie">
 <!-- do notwrap .thumb to use it to access to .hold via CSS -->
<img class="thumb" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/80/nature/1" />
<img class="thumb" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/80/nature/2" />
<img class="thumb" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/80/nature/3" />
<img class="thumb" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/80/nature/4" />
<img class="thumb" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/80/nature/5" />
<img class="thumb" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/80/nature/6" />
<div class="hold">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/800/nature/1" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/800/nature/2" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/800/nature/3" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/800/nature/4" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/800/nature/5" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/800/nature/6" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this quite easily using `background-position` and `width` / `height` properties in combination with the `:hover` pseudo-selector using CSS alone.

For example, if you define the CSS as follows:

```
a.myLink {
    width: 88px;
    height: 88px;
    display: block;
    background: url('http://oi57.tinypic.com/fp4e47.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-position: -4px -10px;
}

a.myLink:hover {
    width: 429px;
    height: 329px;
    background-position: -197px -10px;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AjNeM/)

Notice how I have moved the background image on hover. Remember that in order to specify a size for your `<a>` element, you'll need to define it as a block-level element using `display: block`.

Comment: Thanks, using this technique would I be able to create something like this: http://www.haworthtompkins.com/built/proj43/index.html ?

Comment: I guess so, but the sprite would be huge!